# Bypass Path traversal Filter

Tags: asp.net, security, filter

In my web application I remove these characters:

> ( < ,> ,: ," ,/ ,\ , | ,? ,* )

from my file download url to prevent Path traversal.

Is there any way for to bypass this?

Is it secure ?

Comment: Do you have an example of your download URL - Is the filename in the query string? e.g. www.example.com/download.aspx?filename=foo.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Check out the following guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx but the relevant parts to your problem are highlighted below.

> If you must accept file names as input, use the full name of the file by using System.IO.Path.GetFileName.

also if you want to further secure your site:

> Using Code Access Security to Restrict File I/O
>   An administrator can restrict an application's file I/O to its own virtual directory hierarchy by configuring the application to run with Medium trust. In this event, .NET code access security ensures that no file access is permitted outside of the application's virtual directory hierarchy.
>
> You configure an application to run with Medium trust by setting the  element in Web.config or Machine.config.
>   `<trust level="Medium" />`